# why does the datetime function change the values in my dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to turn a csv into a dictionary with dictreader but there is an abnormality with datetime where its very existence changes my dictionary values.

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=(fields))
    for item in reader:
        duration = item['duration_in_seconds']
        start = item['start_date'] + " " + item['start_time']
        print(start)
        x_as_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(start,"%Y%m%d %H:%M") 
        new_datetime = x_as_datetime + datetime.timedelta(seconds=duration) #add your timedelta
```

when i comment out everythin below `print(start)` the result of the print is:

```
OrderedDict([('channel_id', '69036687'), ('channel_name', 'RTE 1'), 
('channel_country', 'IRL'), ('start_date', '20180228'), 
('start_time', '23:40'), ('duration_in_seconds', '1500'), 
('program_id', '13071731'), ('program_original_title', 'Oireachtas 
Report'), ('program_local_title', 'Oireachtas Report'), 
('program_year', '')])
```

but when I uncomment everything below "print(start)" the result completely changes to:

```
OrderedDict([('channel_id', 'channel_id'), ('channel_name', 
'channel_name'), ('channel_country', 'channel_country'), 
('start_date', 'start_date'), ('start_time', 'start_time'), 
('duration_in_seconds', 'duration_in_seconds'), ('program_id', 
'program_id'), ('program_original_title', 'program_original_title'), 
('program_local_title', 'program_local_title'), ('program_year', 
'program_year')])
```

so all the values are gone. How is this even possible that just by datetime existing it changes my dict?

Comment: what is the result? What is this OrderedDict object?

Comment: Can you expand the snippet to show the print statement that makes the output you pasted? (i.e. the print statement that prints the OrderedDicts?)

Comment: Can you also upload the content of the csv file? 2-3 lines should be sufficient.

Comment: Your output is an `OrderedDict`, which cannot come from the print statement as as shown.  That output must be coming from a part of the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Your second output looks like it's the line printed for the header row of the CSV file.

Comment: You're probably getting an error when you try to parse the `duration_in_seconds` field of the header row, and you're skipping that line.

Comment: Could you please try removing `, fieldnames=(fields)` from the DictReader invocation?. From the docs:  _If fieldnames is omitted, the values in the first row of file f will be used as the fieldname._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird. But it seems like the headers line is prepended to the DictReader result when passing the fieldnames keyword.

```py
$ cat c.csv
channel_id,channel_name
69036687,RTE 1
$ python3
>>> from csv import DictReader
>>> with open('c.csv', 'r') as f:
...   dr = DictReader(f)
...   print([item for item in dr])
... 
[OrderedDict([('channel_id', '69036687'), ('channel_name', 'RTE 1')])]
>>> with open('c.csv', 'r') as f:
...   dr = DictReader(f, fieldnames=['channel_id', 'channel_name'])
...   print([item for item in dr])
... 
[OrderedDict([('channel_id', 'channel_id'), ('channel_name', 'channel_name')]), OrderedDict([('channel_id', '69036687'), ('channel_name', 'RTE 1')])]
```

**EDIT**

From the docs:

> If fieldnames is omitted, the values in the first row of file f will be used as the fieldname

In the other hand, when using `fieldnames=field_names_list`, the DictReader expects a file without a headers line, which means the `field_names_list` order matters here because it'll get mapped to the values in the csv input file.

```
$ cat c.csv
69036687,RTE 1
69036617,RTE 2
$ python3
>>> from csv import DictReader
>>> with open('c.csv', 'r') as f:
...   dr = DictReader(f, fieldnames=['channel_id', 'channel_name'])
...   print(*dr, sep=', ')
OrderedDict([('channel_id', '69036687'), ('channel_name', 'RTE 1')]), OrderedDict([('channel_id', '69036617'), ('channel_name', 'RTE 2')])
```

Comment: Thanks that was part of it but I still dont get why the datetime function was messing with it.